# Using stored procedures in log4net configuration

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm trying to use log4net in my C# console application. I'm not too sure how this is used with stored procedures. With the configuration info below, how exactly will doing something like `log.Info("message here")` execute the stored procedure with parameters if all I pass is the message string?

I'm using SQL Server Express as database. In `AssemblyInfo.cs` I've added the following line:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

From what I've found here on StackOverflow, I have the following in my `app.config`:

```
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
</root>
<configSections>
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="100" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral" />
    <connectionString value="data source=MyPC\\SQLEXPRESSPC;initial catalog=MyDBName;integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=MyDBUser;Password=MyDBPassword" />

    <commandText value="InsertGoogleDriveLog" />
    <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />

    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@user_name" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%username" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message_text" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="1024" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
</appender>
```

In my logger class I have the line:

```
log.Info("OK, here we are");
```

Also, I removed `, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089` from the connectionType string value, as I'm not sure where this is obtained from when I copied it from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034055/how-to-use-stored-proc-inside-log4net-configuration-for-sql-server-for-logging).

Comment: I doubt that this could work if you don't change (or add) one of your root appenders to use the AdoNetAppender

Comment: I don't think you meant to have your username formatted as a `RawTimeStampLayout`

Comment: @Steve , I made the edit just now to the root and added AdoNetAppender.

Comment: @stuartd , right, I should have read this more carefully.

Comment: @Steve , log4net can't execute a stored proc. with given parameters? Initially I was planning to simply log with a function that takes in whatever parameters, and executes the stored proc. It was then suggested by someone that I use log4net, but I'm not sure how this is more efficient.

Comment: You can use `%username` as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541289/how-to-get-current-username-instead-of-apppool-identity-in-a-logfile-with-log4ne), note though that the [documentation on that](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html) says _"Generating caller WindowsIdentity information is extremely slow. Its use should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue."_

Comment: I edited the config file to use %username.

Comment: @stuartd , @ Steve , thank you both for your help. So in gist, using log4net wouldn't necessarily be flexible enough for me. I'd like to log to multiple columns in a table. My table has multiple columns for which the stored proc would insert into, having the column values passed to it. What is the downside of just having a method call to execute the stored proc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you are missing some elements in your configuration (log4net -> should contain the root and appender elements):

```
<configSections>
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net>
 <root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
 </root>
 <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="100" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral" />
    <connectionString value="data source=MyPC\\SQLEXPRESSPC;initial catalog=MyDBName;integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=MyDBUser;Password=MyDBPassword" />

    <commandText value="InsertGoogleDriveLog" />
    <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />

    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@user_name" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%username" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message_text" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="1024" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
 </appender>
</log4net>
```

Comment: thanks. I'm still unsure how stored proc is executed from `log.Info("some message")`. Is the ParameterName value the name of the parameter defined in the stored proc? And what if I had more values to pass for the stored proc? Thanks again.