# Why doesn't Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore support AdoNetAppender and are there plans for it to?

Tags: asp.net-core, log4net, asp.net-core-2.2, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I am using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore (AspNetCore 2.2) and I want to use an AdoNetAppender but it seems like the only option is to make my own or use MicroKnights.Log4NetAdoNetAppender.

- Why doesn't this library support AdoNetAppender?
- Will it ever support it?
- Is there another option?

References:
 - [reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670555/log4net-adonetappender-in-net-core-2-0-not-supported)
 - [reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034055/how-to-use-stored-proc-inside-log4net-configuration-for-sql-server-for-logging)
 - [reference 3](https://www.izenda.com/docs/dev/code_logging_information_to_a_database.html)
 - [reference 4](https://thesoftwayfarecoder.com/integrating-log4net-and-using-adonetappender-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Another possibility https://github.com/ffernandolima/log4netcore-sqlserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore](https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore) is a nuget package that only **connects** the [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0) system and the log4net library, but doesn't implement specifically nothing to make the existing log4net appenders compatible with .NET Core applications.

Maybe you can raise a request to ask for an update for appenders / log4net library at the [log4net official issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/LOG4NET/issues/LOG4NET-599?filter=allopenissues).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It ended up being pretty trivial to implement the MicroKnights version.